# Why is main() argument argv of type char*[] rather than const char*[]?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

When I wrote the following code and executed it, the compiler said

> deprecated conversion from string constant to `char*`

```
int main()  
{  
  char *p;  
  p=new char[5];  
  p="how are you";  
  cout<< p;  
  return 0;  
}
```

It means that I should have written `const char *`.

But when we pass arguments into `main` using `char* argv[]` we **don't** write `const char* argv[]`.

Why?

Comment: Ok but why is it required for char* to be constant while assigning it to a string?

Comment: Your question is interesting, but the code leading up to it is irrelevant. Whether you're allowed to assign string literals to non-cost pointers has nothing to do with the parameter type of `main`. (Also, your code leaks memory.)

Comment: Something else you've overlooked: *We* don't pass arguments into `main`. It's illegal to call `main` from within your program. Calling `main` is something your compiler sets up for you; you're not allowed to do it yourself.

Comment: Also, I believe you are just wasting memory with the `new` call. The string gathers it's own memory from the stack.

Comment: @Rob You do pass parameters to main. Just not directly. But they are the same parameters you pass to `execve` and similar functions.

Comment: Hey thanks guys, ya we pass parameters to main from the terminal right?

Comment: But you're not passing a `const char*`, you're passing a series of characters.  Even if the platform passes the parameters to the program in read-only memory, a lot of steps happen before your program enters `main`, one of which can easily be "copy the parameters somewhere I can write to them."

Comment: There's a memory leak in your example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because ... `argv[]` isn't const. And it certainly isn't a (static) string literal since it's being created at runtime.

You're declaring a  `char *` pointer then assigning a string literal to it, which is by definition constant; the actual data is in read-only memory.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)  {
    // Yes, I know I'm not checking anything - just a demo
    argv[1][0] = 'f';
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Input:

> g++ -o test test.cc
>
> ./test hoo

Output:

> foo

This is not a comment on *why* you'd want to change `argv`, but it certainly is possible.

Comment: You would want to change `argv` if you are accepting any sensitive data as program parameters.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - There's any number of reasons, I just didn't feel they were relevant to the discussion which is why I said I wasn't commenting on that aspect.

Answer (score 12):

Historical reasons. Changing the signature of main() would  break too much existing code. And it is possible that some implementations allow you to change the parameters to main from your code. However code like this:

```
char * p = "helllo";
* p = 'x';
```

is always illegal, because you are not allowed to mess with string literals like that, so the pointer should be to  a const char.

Comment: Your reasoning for `main()` is wrong. `main()` simply can't be invoked using string constants, therefore there is no reason for the parameters to be `const`. See my answer.

Comment: @Let_ My point (and I think what the OP was asking) is that the standard could be changed to make them const, but won't be.

Comment: But that's not the reason. Rewriting `argv[]` is a common technique. It is actually required if you accept any sensitive data as parameters. Therefore the reason isn't historical, it just wouldn't make any sense if you couldn't do it.

Comment: @Let_ What I said: allow you to change the parameters to main from your code.

Comment: lol changing main would break literally every general purpose program ever written

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Is rewriting `argv` guaranteed to prevent the original from being visible through procfs or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

> why is it required for char* to be constant while assigning it to a string

Because such literal strings (like `"hi"`, `"hello what's going on"`, etc), are stored in the **read-only** segment of your exe. As such, the pointers that point to them need to point to **constant characters** (eg, can't change them).

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a string constant (`const char*`) to a pointer to a non-constant string (`char *p`). This would allow you to modify the string constant, e.g. by doing `p[0] = 'n'`.

Anyway, why don't you use `std::string` instead ? (you seem to be using C++).

Comment: u r right, char* is ugly but I am preparing for exams and they might ask this

Answer (score 1):

If you look at execution functions like `execve`, you will see that they actually don't accept `const char*` as parameters, but do indeed require `char*`, therefore you can't use a string constant to invoke `main`.

Comment: You can't invoke `main` at all.

Comment: The current [exec(3) man page for linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) actually *has* those arguments as `const`. Which is no trouble, since the memory of the executing process is distinct from that of the executed one, so things will have to get copied in any case.