# Passing argv as const

Tags: c++, constants, argv

I want to pass `argv` to another function, and can do it with no problems when I define the function like this:

```
void function(char** argv);
```

and call it from `main` with:

```
function(argv);
```

However, I would like to keep everything const where possible (I don't actually plan to change `argv`, or the value of either of the pointers). My problem is that as soon as I add the keyword const anywhere to `argv` in the function declaration I get conversion errors, e.g. this code

```
void function(const char** argv);
```

gives the compile error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const char**’ to ‘char* const*’ [-fpermissive]

I've tried putting const in different places and get similar errors. Is there a way to pass argv while keeping the contents and pointers all constant?

Comment: Save yourself some headaches and store the parameters in a vector of strings and pass that instead. `std::vector<std::string> arguments(argv + 1, argv + argc);`

Comment: With what arguments are you trying to call the function when you get the warning? With which types are they declared?

Comment: @NeilKirk the function I'm passing to calls getopt which takes argv as an argument. If I make my own vector of strings I'd then have to convert it back to a char**, seems like more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: @BugalugsNash Do you have any variable of type `char* const*` in your code? If yes, please add the corresponding code. Also does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14443518/509868) help?

Comment: @sth I've added that info in an edit

Comment: @anatolyg there is no `char* const*` in my code

Comment: Does the compiler say the error is in the call to function, and not something that function is calling?  It kind of looks more like an error from within function.

Comment: @dohashi you are right, the error I reported was due to the code within the function (calling getopt with argv). I should have reported the first error, which occurred at the point where the function was called, and still occurs when the entire body of the function is deleted: `error: invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’ [-fpermissive]`. This may be due to the problem @anatolyg linked to.

Comment: @BugalugsNash getopt expects its argv to be `char * const argv[]`, so you making your argv `const char **` is incompatible.

Comment: [Can the arguments of main's signature in C++ have the unsiged and const qualifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621574/86967)

Comment: [Why is main() argument argv of type char*[\] rather than const char*[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5808679/86967)

Comment: [What is the proper declaration of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4207134/86967)

Comment: There are lots of near-dup's, but the simple answer to this question is: `int main( int argc, char * const argv[] )`

Comment: I think you will benefit from seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to), it really helps me understand.