# C main function const char*[] vs char*[]

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I don't understand what the difference between

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){;}
```

and

```c
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){;}
```

is.

I'm aware of the difference between a `char*[]` and `const char*[]` but I wonder why one would like to use the latter.

Are there use cases where one would want to change command line arguments? What's the best practice about adding `const`?

Comment: The only difference would be that const char does not allow you to modify the data. For example argv[0][0] = 'X'; will in that case throw a compiler error.

Comment: @SvenNilsson: That is not the only difference. The behavior with `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is defined by the C standard. The behavior with `int main(int argc, const char *argv[])` is not, because the types are not compatible and are not interchangeable as function parameter declarations or argument types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is a defined way of declaring `main` for a hosted environment according to the C standard, per C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 1. `int main(int argc, const char *argv[])` is not.

It is good to use `const` where applicable to indicate that the pointed-to objects will not change, but it must be used appropriately. The types `char *[]` and `const char *[]` are not compatible and are not interchangeable as parameter declarations or argument types. If `main` is declared with `const char *argv[]`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

As for why the prescribed declaration is `char *argv[]` rather than `const char *argv[]`, that is partly historical and partly because some techniques for processing command-line arguments modify the arguments in place.

Comment: `char *argv[]` is a defined way of declaring, is it? I thought it's `const char **argv` since `argv` is immutable?

Comment: @marco-a: Neither `argv` nor the pointers it points to nor the strings they point to are immutable. C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 2 says “The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.”

Comment: that is interesting! I just learned something today. I always assumed it to be immutable. (possibly because of the bad practice of modifying user input).

Answer (score 2):

The first one (`char** argv`) is defined by the [C11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
> ```
>
> or equivalent¹⁰) or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> ¹⁰Thus, `int` can be replaced by a `typedef` name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as `char ** argv`, and so on.

You could argue that `const char` is "equivalent" to `char` in the way the C11 standard is defining it. However, the standard also says this about the parameters:

> The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

So it would seem `const` is ***not*** C standard.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963493/is-it-possible-to-change-argv-or-do-i-need-to-create-an-adjusted-copy-of-it) answer details if it's OK to modify `main` parameters. The array `char **argv` is allocated at runtime, and modifying it doesn't affect any program execution.

As to why `const` isn't used as a declaration, it mainly boils down to historical practices. [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808679/why-is-main-argument-argv-of-type-char-rather-than-const-char) detail why `const char **argv` might be used instead of its non-`const`.